# Basis change in General Mechanics problem in Shankar

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, vectors, linear-algebra

I am self-reading R. Shankar and came across a general problem-solving technique using the Eigenvalue problem given in Section 1.8. I have a particular doubt about these equations.

> The solution to the *decoupled* equations
> $$\ddot{x}_i + \omega_i^2 x_i = 0, \quad i=\text{I}, \text{II}\tag{1.8.35}$$
> subject to the condition of vanishing initial velocities is
> $$x_i(t) =  x_i(0) \cos \omega_i t, \quad i=\text{I}, \text{II}\tag{1.8.36}$$
> As anticipated, the components of $|x\rangle$ in the $|\text{I}\rangle$, $|\text{II}\rangle$ basis obey decoupled equations that can be readily solved. Feeding Eq. (1.8.36) into Eq. (1.8.32) we get
> \begin{align}
> |x(t)\rangle &= |\text{I}\rangle x_{\text{I}}(0) \cos\omega_{\text{I}}t + |\text{II}\rangle x_{\text{II}}(0) \cos\omega_{\text{II}}t \tag{1.8.37a} \\
> &= |\text{I}\rangle \langle\text{I}|x(0)\rangle \cos\omega_{\text{I}}t + |\text{II}\rangle \langle\text{II}|x(0)\rangle \cos\omega_{\text{II}}t \tag{1.8.37b}
> \end{align}

Eq. (1.8.35) tells us that $x_i$ which are components of eigenvectors of $\Omega$ in abstract space, follows this simple equation.

Now, I don't understand **how one can write 1.8.37a as 1.8.37b**. Why $x_I(0) = \vert I \rangle x(0)$? Since, they are vectors from different bases set. And one's initial condition (i.e. $x(0)$) can't be necessarily true for other.

Answer (score 0):

You are considering $\vert x(0)\rangle$ as a vector in displacement vector representation, but that is not true. $\vert x(0)\rangle$ is a vector independent of any basis. Therefore, the inner product is valid.

Now, 1.8.36 comes from the fact that the initial velocities are zero in displacement vector representation (I am calling displacement vector representation to the vector space in which the vectors $\vert1\rangle$ & $\vert 2\rangle$ exists). And if those are zero, then the components of eigenvectors will also be zero. $$ \dot{x_i}=0 \ \ \ \ \ \ i\in \{ 1,2,I,II \} $$

Comment: What a solution